# Adding custom latex macros in mathjax_config

Tags: python, latex, python-sphinx, mathjax

I am trying to add a new expectation operator macro for use in some docstrings.

If in the `math` section I do:

```
.. math::
        \newcommand{\EE}[2][]{\mathbb{E}_{#1}\left[#2\right]}

        \EE{2+4}
```

I get the correct output:

[image: Imgur]

If I instead try and place my macro definitions in `mathjax_config` in Sphinx's `conf.py` (by following the instructions [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#defining-tex-macros))

```
mathjax_config = {
    'TeX': {
        'Macros': {
            'EE': [r'{\mathbb{E}_{#1}\left[#2\right]}', 2, r'[]'],
        }
    }
}
```

And my docstring reads:

```
.. math::
        \EE{2+4}
```

then I get two superfluous brackets:

[image: Imgur]

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had a typo:

The MathJax macro definition had an error in the last element (default value), it should have read:

```
'EE': [r'{\mathbb{E}_{#1}\left[#2\right]}', 2, r''],
```